# decrease the mat file size of Dymola result

Tags: modelica, dymola

The result of Dymola simulation is .mat file, which might be very big. Here is a series of results of a Power plant model, the simulation time interval is 0-100000s, but I only need the data during 90000 to 100000s, so is there any way to let Dymola only output the data of 90000 to 100000s?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a section called "Variable frequency of output points" in the Dymola User manual. There you'll find an explanation on how `Advanced.Simulation.VariableInterval=true` and statements like

```
when time >=… then
  Dymola.Simulation.SetOutputInterval(…);
end when;
```

will enable you to set the output interval depending on the simulation time.

The example shown there is:

```
model VariableOutputInterval "demonstrate the use of variable output interval in a model"
  Real x;
equation
  x = sin(10*time);
  
  when initial() then
    Dymola.Simulation.SetOutputInterval(0.1);
  end when;

  when time >= 0.5 then
    Dymola.Simulation.SetOutputInterval(0.05);
  end when;

  when time >= 1.1 then
    Dymola.Simulation.SetOutputInterval(0.002);
  end when;
end VariableOutputInterval;
```

Also there are two notes:

- The only way to “reset” the interval length to the one in the simulation setup is to explicitly set that interval, this is done in the last when statement above.
- You must have a separate when statement for each time.